# SQL show the first and last value in count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, northwind

I need to write a query that show the max and the min count of order the customer order.

I tried:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC)

UNION ALL

(SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

But I don't succeed to union between the output, I got the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'`.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I would want to run the aggregation twice, so use window functions:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Number_Of_Orders
FROM (SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM Orders
      GROUP BY CustomerID
     ) c
WHERE seqnum_asc = 1 OR seqnum_desc = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ORDER BY` inside the queries that you want to unify with `UNION`, but you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC) t
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Orders
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY CustomerID
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) t
```

This does the trick although it is inefficient because you execute **twice** the same code and sort **twice**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this. This will give you multiple customers for min/max if there are ties ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36f1d8d64cf39f961b849899c9dbdd99)):

```
SELECT CustomerID
     , OrderCount
     , CASE WHEN OrderCount = MinOrderCount THEN 'Customer with min orders'
            WHEN OrderCount = MaxOrderCount THEN 'Customer with max orders' END AS Type
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID
         , COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
         , MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS MinOrderCount
         , MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS MaxOrderCount
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS x
WHERE OrderCount = MinOrderCount OR OrderCount = MaxOrderCount
```